# Increasing Vengeance and new targets

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Increasing Vengeance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Increasing%20Vengeance) states "Copy target instant or sorcery spell you control. If Increasing Vengeance was cast from a graveyard, copy that spell twice instead. You may choose new targets for the copies."

Does "You may choose new targets for the copies" apply only if Increasing Vengeance was cast from the graveyard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

You *may* (but are not required to) choose new copies for any or all copies created by Increasing Vengeance. "Copies" in the last sentence refers to any copies the spell produces, even if it's just one.

Note that these types of questions can be easily referenced by [looking up the rulings for Increasing Vengeance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=262661) on Gatherer.